# OGR: How to best use GetFeature on a selection?

Tags: python, ogr, select-by-attribute

I think the following is very confusing

```
sel_str = "ND_14 = '108'"
l.SetAttributeFilter(sel_str)
l.GetFeatureCount()
>>> 1
```

In a for-loop this gives me

```
for f in l:
   g = f.GetGeometryRef()
   print g.GetEnvelope()
>>> (8.39746, 8.95788, 46.52757, 46.99331)
```

Whereas GetFeature() gives me

```
>>> feat0 = l.GetFeature(0)
>>> feat1 = l.GetFeature(1) 
>>> g0 = feat0.GetGeometryRef()
>>> g1 = feat1.GetGeometryRef()
>>> g0.GetEnvelope()
(8.21206, 10.65409, 56.55045, 57.75181)
>>> g1.GetEnvelope()
(10.60014, 10.6172, 57.48933, 57.4979)
```

Apparently `GetFeature()` is based on the FID of the whole set, not the selection. But using a for-loop on a selection of length one is pretty ridiculous. How do I get the FID of my selected feature then? Or what are other ways of using `GetFeature()` with your current selection?

Answer (score 7):

Read Chris Garrard's [Open Source RS/GIS Python,Week 3: Filters & Simple Analysis of Vector Data; Functions & Modules](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_slides3.pdf)

> Resets reading so GetNextFeature() gets the first feature that matches the filter

So, for a selection of length one use the iterator:

```
layer.SetAttributeFilter(sel_str)
sel = layer.GetNextFeature()
g = sel.GetGeometryRef()
g.GetEnvelope()
```

It is easier to use **layer.ExecuteSQL**

Comment: Why is it easier to use `layer.ExecuteSQL`. Can you elaborate a bit on the benefits?

Comment: This behaviour is also mentioned and explained here: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/gotchas.html#filtered-features-are-only-respected-using-getnextfeature